# geolocation keeps on asking for permission

Tags: javascript, html, css, geolocation

I was testing geolocation API and found if I refresh my page, the page keeps on asking for permission, so I saved my coordinate data to local storage but it doesn't works! Is there any way to give permission only once???

```
const COORDINATION = "coords";

function saveCords(coordsOBJ){


    localStorage.setItem(COORDINATION,JSON.stringify(coordsOBJ));

}



function handleGeoError(position){
    console.log("Cant find position");
}

function handleGeoSuccess(position){
   // console.log(position);
   const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
   console.log(latitude);
   const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
   const coordsOBJ = {
       latitude,//latitude = latitude,
       longitude//longitude = longitude
   }
   saveCords(coordsOBJ);

}

function askForCoords(){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleGeoSuccess,handleGeoError);

}

function loadCoordinate(){
    const loadedCords = localStorage.getItem("COORDINATION");
    if(loadedCords === null)
    {
         askForCoords();
    }
}

function init(){
    loadCoordinate();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a typo in your code, whereby you've added quotes to COORDINATION but it's a varible not a string.

Try changing:

```
const loadedCords = localStorage.getItem("COORDINATION");
```

To:

```
const loadedCords = localStorage.getItem(COORDINATION);
```

Comment: Jesus.... thanks so much! I've waste a day cuz of this silly question...